# mysql update field with value from another field in same table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table like this:

```
----------------------------------
| id | date1      | date2 | type |
----------------------------------
| 1  | NULL       | NULL  | A    |
| 1  | NULL       | NULL  | B    |
| 1  | NULL       | NULL  | A    |
| 1  | NULL       | NULL  | A    |
| 1  | 2016-08-02 | NULL  | C    |
| 1  | NULL       | NULL  | B    |
| 2  | NULL       | NULL  | A    |
| 2  | NULL       | NULL  | A    |
| 2  | NULL       | NULL  | A    |
| 2  | NULL       | NULL  | B    |
| 2  | 2016-08-15 | NULL  | C    |
| 2  | NULL       | NULL  | B    |
----------------------------------
```

and I would like that become by single query like this:

```
----------------------------------------
| id | date1      | date2       | type |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | NULL       | 2016-08-02  | A    |
| 1  | NULL       | 2016-08-02  | B    |
| 1  | NULL       | 2016-08-02  | A    |
| 1  | NULL       | 2016-08-02  | A    |
| 1  | 2016-08-02 | NULL        | C    |
| 1  | NULL       | 2016-08-02  | B    |
| 2  | NULL       | 2016-08-15  | A    |
| 2  | NULL       | 2016-08-15  | A    |
| 2  | NULL       | 2016-08-15  | A    |
| 2  | NULL       | 2016-08-15  | B    |
| 2  | 2016-08-15 | NULL        | C    |
| 2  | NULL       | 2016-08-15  | B    |
----------------------------------------
```

The date to get will be always "type C" and the field to update will be always the same id of the date and "type A" or "type B"

Any suggest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an updated  joined on subselect

```
 update my_table 
 inner join  ( select id, date1 from my_table where type ='C') t2
 on my_table.id = t2.id
 set date2 = t2.date1
 where type in ('A','B')
```

Comment: This is better, you only calculate the `date` once for `id`. I was adding an update but was too slow :(

Comment: your answer  is good too ..but  the use of inner join  i think is more SQL oriented   (as well as more powerful)

Comment: My answer solve the problem, but your is more scalable.

Comment: Thanks so much for support... just an edit... 
update my_table 
 inner join  ( select id, date1 from my_table where type ='C') t2
 on my_table.id = t2.id
 set date2 = t2.date1
 where type='A' or type='B'

Comment: @FrancescoG.   .many .thanks  ..where is needed  the edit /update .. looking to the code seems the same  ..

Comment: (set date2 = date1 ---> set date2 = t2.date1) and (where type<>'C' ---> where type='A' or type='B')

Comment: @FrancescoG.   answer  updated  ...used   IN   insetad of  OR

Comment: I have never use... difference?

Comment: for performance no ..  more  .. easy add  others value .. and (for me) more clear to read ..

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myTable t1
SET date2 = (SELECT MAX(date1)
             FROM myTable t2 
             WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
WHERE t1.type <> 'C'
```